# Trouble with the box model

Tags: html, css

I have a container that I am calling #profile-grid and I want it to be 330px wide. It contains an image that is 330px wide and an inline list below the image that is 330px wide with a 1px border all around. I want the list and image to be exactly the same width. In IE it lines up perfect, but in Chrome it is 2px too short. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ZPQUP/13/

Comment: is the image supposed to have this black "stripe" at the right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as your title suggested, the box model.

Your best bet is to just explicitly set the box model, and then use a polyfill to make it work for older browsers. Paul Irish describes the problem and solution here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

I've shown what this looks like in an updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mstauffer/ZPQUP/14/

Essentially, the different box models differ on whether borders and paddings are *included in* or *added externally to* the width.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPQUP/16/):

HTML:

```
<div id="profile-grid">
    <img src="http://a8.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/428132_268919676513976_100001878373747_678116_241912084_n.jpg"/>
    <ul id="listed">
            <li class="item"><a href="#"> Profile </a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#"> About </a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#"> Photos </a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="#"> Albumlist </a></li>
        </ul>    
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#profile-grid {
    height: 302px;
    width: 330px;
}

#profile-grid img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#listed {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li.item {
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: inline;
}

#listed li a {
    display: block;
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #123454;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0px 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

#listed li a:hover{
    font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #123454;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

NOTES:

- `<ul>` is a block element. whatever the width of the parent, it grows with it. sort of an automatic 100%. give the parent 330px, it also goes 330px.
- as long as block elements don't have a specified width, the 100% width of it will include it's borders. so if you have a parent of 330px, the block element (in this case the `<ul>`) will be 298px wide + 1px left border + 1px right border.
- on the other hand, specifying width for it will exclude borders in the count, thus the overflow.
- giving an image `display:block` and `width:100%` also does the same thing PLUS it preserves the image ratio (and not squishing it in any way)

​

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, it is ideal to not mix `width` and `padding` or `border` on the same element.

In your case, if you simply remove the `width: 330px` from `.listed` and add it to `.listed ul` instead, you should be fine:

```
#listed {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}



#listed ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -1px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 330px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div#listed` is 330px wide *plus* 1 pixel either side for the border. That's how the 'standard' box model works. Reduce the width by that 1 pixel each side (i.e. 298px) and everything will line up...

... in the good browsers. In older versions of IE, you'll see a problem. Use a valid DOCTYPE and that will be resolved.